# how to update state with in method in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

There is a state and i want to update this state with in a function.
In function i declared a variable and i want to update state with this variable.

```
this.state = {
       RequestData : [],
       searchopen : false,
       capturedImage : ""
  }


screenShot = () => {

       html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {
         document.body.appendChild(canvas);
         // Get base64URL
          var base64URL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg').replace('image/jpeg', 'image/octet-stream');


       });

       this.setState({capturedImage: base64URL})
     }
```

Comment: I think you need to move `this.setState({capturedImage: base64URL})` inside the `then` callback

Answer (score 1):

You need to put setState in function that get base64URL and bind your `screenShot` function to use `this.setState`:

```js
// constructor
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        RequestData: [],
        searchopen: false,
        capturedImage: ""
    }
    this.screenShot = this.screenShot.bind(this);
}

screenShot = () => {
    html2canvas(document.body).then(function (canvas) {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        // Get base64URL
        var base64URL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg').replace('image/jpeg', 'image/octet-stream');

        this.setState({ capturedImage: base64URL })
    }.bind(this)); // bind here also
}
```

Comment: I already tried this but it's not working. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: thanks to help. this is working well. Thanks a  lot.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are doing the state update outside the callback function. Since this is a asynchronous task, your method will not work. Try this:

```
screenShot = () => {

   html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {
     document.body.appendChild(canvas);

     // Get base64URL
      var base64URL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg').replace('image/jpeg', 'image/octet-stream');

        this.setState({capturedImage: base64URL})
   });   
 }
```

Comment: i try this but this give me "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined" error

Comment: Show us the whole component. Edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty but should work

```
this.state = {
       RequestData : [],
       searchopen : false,
       capturedImage : ""
  }


screenShot = () => {
      var setState = newStore => this.setState((state, props) => ({ ...newStore })); // define the function outside

       html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {
         document.body.appendChild(canvas);
         // Get base64URL
          var base64URL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg').replace('image/jpeg','image/octet-stream');

          setState({capturedImage: base64URL}) // use here
       });
}
```